# Cloud run can't handle POST method

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run

I just deployed an application into cloud run, but the application running in cloud run can't handle the request in the form of POST method and always returns 404 not found. After I checked the log, whatever request was given it was always translated into the get method. What should I do to prevent the given method from being translated like that?

the log:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the HTTP 302 response on your POST. That means the client is being instructed to go to a new **Location**. Your client is then converting the POST into a GET and making another request at the new location.

Cloud Run only supports HTTPS. Your POST request is being sent to an HTTP endpoint. The Cloud Run frontend will automatically redirect the client to the HTTPS endpoint.

Change your request from using HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: wow thank you, it solved what i wondering about it.